# Can the new winget preview to install or update PSModules (non-Microsoft PS-Modules like from gallery)?

Tags: winget

In the near future I'm going to pitch to my team to use winget to manage "dotnet-SDK" versions, python versions, powershell, VSCode, and a bunch of open source tools (some running in WSL2).

As part of that can I consolidate `winget` and powershell `Install-Module` in powershell 7+?  I see they're adding WinGet powershell modules.  Are there or any plans to manage professional pwsh modules with `winget`?

examples of pwsh modules I'd like other developers on my team to install:

- [DbaTools](https://dbatools.io/)
- [winget preview](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/tag/v1.5.1361-preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just use `Install-Module` until Powershell-DSC is ready?
With `-Force` to install newer version if older version is present?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is coming with the PowerShell DSC integration for `winget`, currently in preview, as shown in:

- https://youtu.be/9HlM0xuu01M

  - MSBuild event, session BRK280H | English (US) | Windows
- to enable the DSC preview feature get the JSON from:

  - https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/tag/v1.5.1361-preview
  - (manual step after installing the preview CLI app)

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/package-manager/configuration/